# advice how to save html table to SQL server

Tags: asp.net, html, sql-server, xml

I am trying to save html table to sql server table with unique name and save its data in a database. 
For example, I have a html table like this(it is dynamically created in browser by user).

[image: int varchar(20)]

I use asp.net, C#, Sql Server 2008 express.
How can after clicking on save button, create table with unique name, 2 colums int and varchar(40) types, and insert data?

I think it is possible by rendering table to XML, and then work this xml on C# classes, then save in database.

What you sing about it?

Added after edit?

i want save this:

```html
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td>int</td>
           <td>varchar(40)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td>USA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>2</td>
           <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>3</td>
           <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

like this:

```
CREATE TABLE uniqueName
(key int,
values varchar(50)) 

INSERT INTO uniqueName (key, values)
       VALUES (1,  'USA') 
INSERT INTO uniqueName (key, values)
       VALUES (2,  'Canada') 
INSERT INTO uniqueName (key, values)
       VALUES (3,  'Mexico')
```

will help peace of code more:) or links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create two tables - one for the entry for the Html table as such (with an `ID` guaranteed to be unique, and a name for the Html table), and another one for the data contained in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.HtmlTables
(ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
 HtmlTableName VARCHAR(100)  -- or whatever length you need
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.HtmlTableData
(ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
 HtmlTableID INT NOT NULL,
 Sequence INT NOT NULL,
 Key INT,
 Value VARCHAR(500)
)
```

You'll want to create a foreign key referential integrity between the two tables on the `HtmlTables.ID` field:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.HtmlTableData
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_HtmlTableData_HtmlTables
  FOREIGN KEY(HtmlTableID) REFERENCES dbo.HtmlTables(ID)
```

and you most likely also want to make sure each sequence number shows up only once for each HtmlTableID, so create a unique index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX01_HtmlTableData
  ON dbo.HtmlTableData(HtmlTableID, Sequence)
```

Now you could store each HTML table into an entry in `dbo.HtmlTables`, and each row in the grid can be stored into a row in `dbo.HtmlTableData` and be associated with the HTML table entry through the foreign key relationship, and it will be sequenced properly by means of the `Sequence` field.