# How to add a new data and display on the next button click

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am working on a program that contains a set of question to train SQL Syntax to the user. Currently, my program consists of 10 question that I created it on using page (e.g. : page1.aspx is for question 1, etc).
But my mentor ask me to add a feature so that another person able to add a new question through the system itself not by code like the one that I already created by using html code on the page.

Each question consist of table, SQL query for the answer, the keyword, and also the user input.

There are two way that I am working on: 
1. I am thinking to put the data into a database and called it using dropdownlist, but I am stuck about how to insert a table to the database, I have already search it through internet but nothing come up.

2. So, I try another way to create the question using page but I dont know the code to create a new page for each question to be added?

   Is there any other way to add a new question through the system and can be display by button click?

I am really sorry for the long question, I am really stuck and don't have the idea to make the flow of the system.

Comment: what is your problem ? u want add multiple datas or multiple rows to database in a single query? or u want to add a new question by the user and save it to database and show it when somebody needs it ? or automatically show that question ?

Comment: I only want to add a table created by HTML code to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML table and Relational Database table are different entities, HTML table is only a visual representation of data, relational database table is entity in specific database (you can have several databases, each database can have several tables) stored on disc (on server usually).

HTML table can have dynamic rows/columns, but RD table can have dynamic rows only, NOT columns, (not fairly true, some RDBMS allows removing columns).

so  You can parse the table with `jQuery,` create `client side array or object`

their is some another methods. i think the below link deals the question already check it
[advice how to save html table to SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375047/advice-how-to-save-html-table-to-sql-server)

Comment: @Tri.PS. i don't think it is necessary to save html table to your database .What is the way we store data into database it is 100% our idea and our wish . the problem is how we show that data into users screen . so u can save the data into DB several ways . u can save it as a single string. the point is that when u retrieving the data from database we arrange the data like what the user needed.

Comment: oh... I see. I get it what you mean. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Tri.PS if my ans is working for u  then tick it as right ans

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt to solve the problem was right. You should use SQL to manage your question data. However, as you discovered, you cannot store a table within a table. What you can do, however, is create a table for each question (if the data is totally different from one question to another) and then link to that table.

Your SQL structure for each question should be like this

Question Table => SQL query for the answer, the keyword, Table Name (this will be the table that contains the table data)
Table Data for Question => Rows containing the data related to a question number

Then in your code, you need to right a query that will pull this information from the two tables, aggregate it and display it on the page. If you use this approach, you will only ever need to create one page instead of multiples for each question.

Comment: for example, If I created a table for every each question, then there will be so many table in the database right? what should I do to differentiate it for each question?

Comment: Please note that what I mean by storing the table data for each question is this: don't store the rendered HTML table, but the data required to populate the HTML table. Your presentation layer should be totally agnostic of the data(base) layer. Each table will have a unique ID. I believe that you need to read up a little bit on relational data design or have a chat with someone that can explain some of the basics. It will enhance your application's performance and make things more efficient all around.